# ProgressDialog#setIndeterminate(false) not working

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm trying to display a determinate progress dialog with a bar, however, I can't get it to working. Here is how I create it:

`dialog = ProgressDialog.show(from, "Posting...", "Uploading...");`

Then on UI thread (calling within `runOnUiThread`), I'm calling:

`dialog.setIndeterminate(false);`

However, when I inspect after it (both immediately after setting, and in progress handler afterwards which is invoked independently while uploading a file), it's `isIndeterminate()` method returns `true`. I've also tried:

`dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);`

But it also didn't change anything (still, indeterminate indicator is spinning instead of a progress bar). I've set it's max to 100, and my progress handler is being invoked with perfectly valid values between 0 and 100, and I'm calling all dialog methods on UI thread, but nothing changes. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the style of the progress after showing the ProgressBar what you can do is to prepare it first then show it.

```
progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setTitle("title");
progressDialog.setMessage("message");
progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
progressDialog.show();
```

OR

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(from, "Posting...", "Uploading...", false);
```

Comment: Creating the dialog explicitly instead of the static show method worked for me. Thanks.